Issues with 2-Channel Relay Songle SLA-05VDC-SL-C Stuck in NC State
I am experiencing an issue with a 2-channel 30A relay (Songle SLA-05VDC-SL-C). The relay always remains in the NC (normally closed) state and does not switch to NO (normally open), even when I try to control it with my code. I do not hear the characteristic "clack" sound of activation/deactivation.
To troubleshoot, I tested with an older relay of the same model, and it works perfectly with the same setup and code, so I am confident the wiring and code are correct.
Here are my setup and the code I am using with an ESP32:
const int Rele1Pin = 33;
const int Rele2Pin = 26;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  delay(3000);

  pinMode(Rele1Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Rele2Pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(Rele1Pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Rele2Pin, HIGH);

  delay(2000);

  digitalWrite(Rele1Pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Rele2Pin, LOW);

  delay(2000);
}

Connections:
Image 1: Connections DC+, DC-, CH1, CH2.
Image 2: Power supply from a 12V battery.



Do you have enough power to power the relay?

Yes, the led is turning on normally.. and with the old relay works too..

To power the coils, how much current do you need? How much does your supply have?

Im powering the DC+ with 5V from esp32

As far as I know, this relay needs 5V to turn on

Power it from a bench supply with a short wire and see if it works.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No relays need current AND voltage. Measure the current from the coil and see if it is enough.

I dont have a bench supply, do you have other suggestion to try ?

I don't think you have a problem with the relay, but with the PCB module the relay is mounted on. Unless you have a manual how to use the module, we cannot tell you if it is used right or wrong.

I suspect that the COM terminal on the input terminal block should be connected to the ESP 32 Ground.

I dont have the manual of the module, ill try to get from where i buy it

And i tried to add the COM terminal with the ESP32 Ground and not works

I found what is it! The wire of CH1 and CH2 was supplying with 3v from esp32, and i connected an arduino uno in 5V wire and connect with the relay and worked!

I found what was the problem.
The problem was my CH1/CH2 is using esp32 GPIO that supply only 3.3v, and to activate the relay, its mandatory 5v
